# String to NSDate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

I am trying to convert string to date. have used the following code. But getting wrong date.

Thanks,

```
NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"12-07-2011"];
//NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-%d-%d", selectedDate.day, selectedDate.month, selectedDate.year];
NSLog(@"%@",dateString);

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-mm-yyyy"];

NSDate* d = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"%@",d);               
                      
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Selected Date" message: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",d] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Comment: You need to explain further. What date to you get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is you are using the minute and not the month. `M`

`[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];`

[Unicode Date Format Patterns](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
```